# Fit image inside parent div and maintain aspect ratio?

Tags: html, css

I have a dynamic image, sometimes its portrait, sometimes it is landscape. I wish to fit this 100% to it's parent div and still preserve aspect ratio.

I am aware similar questions have been asked before but I have a few stipulations:

- No background cover
- No object fit
- No JS

Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe by setting just one size-attribute f.e. `<img src="image1.jpg" height="100%" /> <img src="image2.jpg" height="100%" />` ?

Comment: That does not work, it stretches landscape images.

Comment: I don't see how this should be possible without using background-cover or Javascript.

Comment: In surprisingly many cases it is possible to add a class to the image when adding it. Then you can do `<img src="image1.jpg" class="image-landscape" />` and in the css you have `.image-landscape{height:100%; width:auto;}` and vice versa for portrait.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to fit image (100%) inside a container and maintain aspect ratio without using background-cover or js. You are providing either a landscape or a portrait image which has to be stretched horizontally or vertically to fit the div 100%.

Comment: Ok, just wanted to know if there was a non bg cover CSS solution, thanks.